# Export a TypeScript module with classes from different files

Tags: class, typescript, module, export, systemjs

There are several questions on how to split TypeScript modules with classes in separate files but so far no solution applied to my issue.

I have one module (`store`) which includes two classes (`Person` & `SerialisedRecord`). When both classes are in one file, the compilation and export works fine.

Now I want to have one file for each class (`Person.ts` & `SerialisedRecord.ts`), following the same export schema I already have. But I don't know how to achieve this.

Here is my initial situation:

**store.ts**

```
export module store {

  export class Person {
    public fullName: string = '';

    constructor(firstName: string, lastName: string) {
      this.fullName = `${firstName} ${lastName}`;
    }
  }

  export class SerialisedRecord {   
    constructor(public serialised: string, public id: string) {}
  }

}
```

When I compile `store.ts` to `store.js` (ES5), I get exactly what I want (a SystemJS module exporting both classes in one module):

```
System.register([], function(exports_1, context_1) {
    "use strict";
    var __moduleName = context_1 && context_1.id;
    var store;
    return {
        setters:[],
        execute: function() {
            (function (store) {
                var Person = (function () {
                    function Person(firstName, lastName) {
                        this.fullName = '';
                        this.fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;
                    }
                    return Person;
                }());
                store.Person = Person;
                var SerialisedRecord = (function () {
                    function SerialisedRecord(serialised, id) {
                        this.id = id;
                        this.serialised = serialised;
                    }
                    return SerialisedRecord;
                }());
                store.SerialisedRecord = SerialisedRecord;
            })(store = store || (store = {}));
            exports_1("store", store);
        }
    }
});
```

Now I tried to do this:

```
export module store {
  export {Person} from "./Person";
  export {SerialisedRecord} from "./SerialisedRecord";
}
```

But it fails telling me:

> error TS1194: Export declarations are not permitted in a namespace.

Can you tell me what I do wrong?

Here is my **tsconfig.json**:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/browser",
    "typings/browser.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works great if you remove the store module:

store.ts:

```
export { Person } from "./Person";
export { SerialisedRecord } from "./SerialisedRecord";
```

index.ts:

```
import { Person, SerialisedRecord } from "./store";

let p = new Person("first", "last");
```

---

#### Edit

If you must keep the namespace structure, you can try something like:

```
import Person from "./Person";
import SerialisedRecord from "./SerialisedRecord";

export default {
    store: {
        Person,
        SerialisedRecord
    }
}
```

Comment: But then my [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) module doesn't contain `exports_1("store", store);`, which means that my namespace `store` will not be available when loading my module.

Comment: Why do you need it if there's nothing in it?

Comment: I want to have it to structure my app into JS namespaces like `module.store`, `module.notification`, `module.audio` and such.

Comment: But that approach made sense when all scripts were loaded into the same global namespace, but when you're using a module system then it makes less sense. But check my revised answer.

Comment: Ok, this works! :) Very important is that `Person` and `SerialisedRecord` use `export default class`, like `export default class Person`.